# On the uncertainty principle when a gamma-ray burst is passing close enough of the magnetic bubbles placed at the edge of a planetary system

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, astrophysics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, gamma-rays

I'm going to ask a related question to my past post [*Collision or impact of a gamma-ray burst against the magnetic bubbles at Solar System's edge*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533993/collision-or-impact-of-a-gamma-ray-burst-against-the-magnetic-bubbles-at-solar-s) on this site Physics Stack Exchange.

I have no a good background in physics but I know that the the detection of quantum effects is very delicated in macroscopic systems: there may be a loss in detecting these effects in a physical system (if the scale of the system is large). My belief as a partial solution of my previous post is that there is a 
materialization of time–energy uncertainty principle (I mean that it applies in this case, that the principle has some consequence that I'm not able to elucidate/figure out) in the scenario in which a gamma-ray burst travels/passes close enough to the magnetic bubbles (please see [1], or the linked post) at a solar system's edge (similar than ours Solar System).

> **Question.** I would like to know if it happens than should be some consequence or materialization of time–energy uncertainty principle in the event in which a very energetic gamma-ray burst travels/passes close enough to the magnetic bubbles placed at a solar system's edge (similar than our planetary system). If there aren't consequences, I mean if the time–energy uncertainty principle does not apply in this event (or this materialization should not be appreciable) explain why. **Many thanks.**

In your discussion, you can to consider the system

$$\text{a gamma-ray burst passing close enough of the mentioned magnetic bubbles},$$ or well if it have a better physical meaning the system including the full planetary system

$$\text{a gamma-ray burst passing close enough of a planetary system, and its magnetic bubbles.}$$

I hope that it is possible say something about it, and my question is suitable since I admit that I've persuaded without a clear justification that that there is some interesting physics in this problem. If you know references about if there is some application of the uncertainty principle in previous scenario, feel free to refer it and I try to search and read it from the literature.

### References:

[1] *NASA |Voyager Finds Magnetic Bubbles at Solar System's Edge*, from the offcial channel **NASA Goddard** of YouTube (June, 9th 2011).

Comment: To clarify the word "materialization ", I add that I understand physical realization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be any strong effect of gamma rays, photons, passing through magnetic fields, even if strong fields. This is due to the effect that photon photon interactions are highly improbable due to the coupling constant (1/137) entering the QED calculation. To illustrate how the lowest order  Feynman diagram would look for photon-magnetic field interactions :

[image: gammagamma]

Take a gamma entering from the top left  and going out from the bottom left.  It can only "see" the magnetic field only interacting with [virtual photons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) due to the field B

In addition to having four electromagnetic vertices, it also needs the exchange of charged virtual particles which will also diminish the probabilities.

So the effect would not be measurable.The burst would go through the bubble unscathed.

The Heisenberg uncertainty applies to individual particles , and the effect of the field is too small to change either direction or energy of individual gammas.

To get the order of magnitude, $~h/{2π}=6.610^{-16} electon volts$, a very small number, that is why the relation is always fulfilled macroscopically.

Considering that the measurements would happen on satellites, it is doubtful that even if the bursts were coherent  ( so individual scatters would be detectable), the small probability scatters by the B field would be detectable with the present technology.